# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client (error when i'm striking axios post requrest)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

**I'm sending response to my Axios call but I'm keep getting the above error **

```
import User from "../model/UserSchema.js"
export const getuser = async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json("hello from code with himanhsu 12315464968 darling")
    try {
        let user = await User.find()
        res.json(user)
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message })
    }

}
```

error .. :
**Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\HIMANSHU\Documents\REACT\16_MERN_operations\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\HIMANSHU\Documents\REACT\16_MERN_operations\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
at getuser (file:///C:/Users/HIMANSHU/Documents/REACT/16_MERN_operations/server/controller/UserContoller.js:9:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection,

*my API call from axios *

```
import axios from "axios"
const url = "http://localhost:8000/users"
export const getUsers = async () => {
return await axios.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of this line in your express function

```js
res.status(200).json("hello from code with himanhsu 12315464968 darling")
```

You will then have this

```js
import User from "../model/UserSchema.js"
export const getuser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.find()
        res.json(user)
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```js
res.status(200).json("hello from code with himanhsu 12315464968 darling")
```

It writes the response `headers`. You again call `res.json()` which also writes response headers, but the `headers` have already been sent previously.

You need to make sure you call `res.json` once.

```js
import User from "../model/UserSchema.js"
export const getuser = async (req, res) => { 
// res.status(200).json("hello from code with himanhsu 12315464968 darling")
    try {
        let user = await User.find()
        res.json(user) // status 200 is default here
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message }).status(400)
    }

}
```